# Rails find and redirect or Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a Create action in my model where it first checks to see if there is already an object in the database based on the params that I have. If there is, I would like to redirect to the show page for that object. If not, I would like to create an object using the params. How would I do this and what's the best 'Rails way' to accomplish it? I tried find_or_create_by but just ended up with duplicate entries in my database, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Here is my create action so far:

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  if @book.save
    redirect_to @book
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

I have my params set up this way:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :isbn, :description)
end
```

I also have a uniqueness validation on :isbn.

```
  validates :isbn, presence: true, length: { is: 13 }, uniqueness: true, numericality: true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `before_filter` that runs before your `create` that does a query and then redirects out.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_for_existing_book, :only => [:create]

  def create
    # your existing create logic here
  end

  private

  def check_for_existing_book
    book = Book.where(:isbn => params[:book][:isbn]).first
    if book
      redirect_to(book) and return
    end
  end
end
```

You'll probably want to clean up the logic for inspecting `params[:book][:isbn]` and ensure you don't bomb out on invalid input, but this is the gist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's great. I was setting up a similar private method but couldn't get it to work. Didn't think to use a before_action.

Comment: One more thing to note: I'm building on rails 4 so I had to make a slight adjustment by using...   before_action :check_for_existing_book, only: [:create]

Comment: @CodyCaughlan should the "uniqueness" logic resides in Model?

Comment: @fengd yes I think so, if it makes sense for the application and in this case it appears so. I'd probably do two things: 1) keep the `validates_uniqueness_of` in the Model, and 2) add an unique index on `books.isbn` in the database.